# How do I install a DMG file from the command line?

Tags: python, macos, bash

I am looking for small bash or python script that will install a `.dmg` file.

We'll assume that the dmg contains one or more `.app` directories that have to be copied to `/Applications`, overriding any already existing directories.

Files or directories not matching the `*.app` pattern are to be ignored.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can mount the disk image using

```
hdiutil attach -mountpoint <path-to-desired-mountpoint> <filename.dmg>
```

The disk image will be mounted at the selected path (the argument following `-mountpoint`). Then, search for an `.app` file and copy the file to `/Applications`.

Once you have finished installation unmount the disk image:

```
hdiutil detach <path-to-mountpoint>
```

Comment: This only works if you know the name of the .DMG file. It would be nice to have a script that could detect the last downloaded DMG file in the ~/Downloads directory so that the entire process could be automated.

Comment: in my case there was ```.pkg``` file inside ```jdk-7u40-macosx-x64.dmg```, after that I run ```sudo installer -pkg path/to/file.pkg -target /``` as described here: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20030614230204397

Comment: Is it possible to know in advance what <path-to-mountpoint> will be?